# Заменить onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице много таких input и все без ID

```js
function doAdd(btn) {
  var c = getCookie('m_ids');
  if (c) {
    var a = c.split(',');
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      if (a[i] == btn.alt) {
        alert('');
        return false;
      }
    }
    a.push(btn.alt);
    setCookie('m_ids', a.join(','), '', '/');
  } else {
    setCookie('m_ids', btn.alt, '', '/');
  }
  order('cost', 'alt');
  ordc();
  return false;
}
```

```html
<input class="button btn js-add-to-cart" alt="^[$id]" value="Добавить в заказ" readonly="readonly" onclick="return doAdd(this)">
```

Как заменить `onclick="return doAdd(this)"` на `$('body').on('click', smth, function(e)`

Comment: Объедините инпуты каким-то общим параметром, например классом или каким-нибудь другим атрибутом, например name

Comment: У них общий class. Скрипт берет alt каждого инпута и в куки добавляет. Но если вызывать без явного onclick прям на инпуте - скрипт не знает где взять alt и добавляет пустой.

Comment: В чем причина желания замены? разметка при этом остается той же?

Comment: Причина в том, что на этот же инпут у меня повешена еще одна функция, которая срабатывает от $('body').on('click') - а если в самом элементе есть onclick то глобальный не срабатывает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рабочий вариант в соответствии с комментарием под вопросом о cookies.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function newAdd() {
    console.log($(this).attr("alt"));
    setCookie('yourID', $(this).attr("alt"),5);
}

var elementList = document.querySelectorAll('input.button');
for (i = 0; i < elementList.length; i++) {
    elementList[i].onclick = newAdd;
}
```

Comment: Сделал как вы написали. Функция выполняется, но в куки вписыватеся пустота. Про это и был вопрос, как вытащить значение из alt и вписать его в куки.  Просто вставить мой скрипт внутрь newAdd - не работает.

Comment: не увидел коммент с этими уточнениями

Comment: обновил пример, он рабочий, но в сниппете он не может работать по причине The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag. Поэтому сниппет убрал.

Comment: Работает, отлично! Спасибо!